# how to insert frame to update materials

Tags: python, animation, materials, keyframes

I have a project where i would like to store frames of my scene in which there are several objects that move and change material from frame to frame.

In a loop, i have been able to make the objects move then store the frames with

```
current_obj.location = (newx, newy, newz)
current_obj.keyframe_insert(data_path="location", frame=dayID)
```

i wish now to also save material related changes of my objects.

This is how i change the material of an object

```
current_obj.data.materials.clear()
current_obj.data.materials.append(matRed)
```

I have tried

`current_frame.keyframe_insert(data_path='data.material', frame=dayID)`

but it returns the error

`TypeError: bpy_struct.keyframe_insert() property "data.material" not found`

I also have tried [this](https://blenderartists.org/t/trying-to-set-keyframes-using-data-path-and-setattr/1323026) approach but it won't work

How do i apply material changes to the frames ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can really only animate numeric values. So you'll need to set things up so there's a number you can change to change your materials.

One simple way (if you only use one material per object) is to use Geometry Nodes. The "Set Material Index" node can change which material slot is used.

[image]

By setting the *Material Index* socket to 1, the mesh changes to use Blue (slots[1]) instead of Red (slots[0]). So you would do something like

```
grp = ob.modifiers["GeometryNodes"].node_group
grp.nodes["Set Material Index"].inputs[2].default_value = 1
grp.keyframe_insert(
    'nodes["Set Material Index"].inputs[2].default_value',
    frame=...,
)
```

You will probably want to turn off interpolation between the keyframe values too. You can do that by running this after inserting all the keyframes

```
action = ob.modifiers["GeometryNodes"].animation_data.action
kps = action.fcurves[0].keyframe_points
for kp in kps:
    kp.interpolation = 'CONSTANT'
```

Comment: ob being the current_object i presume ?
The blender object is stored as a bpy.context.object and there is no "GeometryNodes" key attached to it

Comment: ob being the object you want to animate. You will of course have to first create the Geometry Node modifier and the node setup shown.

Comment: Could you explain how to setup the Node modifier ?
I am using blender 3.3.1
`mod = obj.modifiers.new("GeometryNodes", 'NODES')`
`ng = mod.node_group`
`node = ng.nodes.new("SetMaterialIndex")`
last line won't work because nodes is not an attribute

Comment: Here's a complete example: https://gist.github.com/scurest/7036f6f889a9b2f6773721066b448c83

Comment: Tanks a lot but this changes all my objects's material, i was hoping for something that would change only a chosen one

Comment: You can use the "Selection" socket to filter which polys to apply it to. For example [Material Index]->[Compare Equal to 2]->[Selection] will change only polys assigned to slot 2. The important idea is just that you have a numeric value you can animate.

Comment: What do you mean by [Material Index]->[Compare Equal to 2]->[Selection]

Comment: I have been able to make it work by assigning a unique node group to each of my objects

Answer (score 0):

update:

use this:

```
import bpy


def my_handler(scene):    
    bpy.data.objects["Cube"].material_slots[0].material = bpy.data.objects["Cube"].material_slots[scene.frame_current].material
    

bpy.app.handlers.frame_change_pre.append(my_handler)
```

you need for this:

1. an object which is called "Cube"
2. several materials on this cube (as many as you have frames in your scene + 1)

i have rendered from frame 1 to 3 and had these materials:

[image]

result was this:

[image]

---

instead of keyframing it i would use the frame-pre-handler to assign the material you want:

```
import bpy


def my_handler(scene):
    #assign your material here


bpy.app.handlers.frame_change_pre.append(my_handler)
```

here is explained how the handlers work: https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.app.handlers.html

Comment: I can't find enough explanantions and exemples to make it work. If you could provide a working exemple that would be a precious help.

Comment: Thanks. I have been able to work with the following :

`scene = bpy.context.scene`
`bpy.app.handlers.frame_change_pre.clear()`
`bpy.app.handlers.frame_change_pre.append(lambda scene: myHandler(scene, arg1, arg2, ...))`